Олимпиада по информатике и работа программиста
Насколько работа программиста схожа с олимпиадой по информатике? Там тоже прям обязательно делать программу так, чтобы она была менее затратной по времени и ресурсам?

Отвечу вопросом на вопрос. Вот есть спортивные олимпиады. Насколько то, что спортсмены делают на олимпиаде, похоже на повседневную жизнь? Обычно вообще не похоже. Вот тоже самое и с олимпиадами.
Да, на каких-то задачах нужно делать код прямо на грани эффективности по времени и ресурсам. Но это мало где так. Если только это обработка миллионов запросов в секунду, как на крупных маркетплейсах или в крупных поисковиках. Но обычно гораздо важнее, чтобы код надёжно работал, чтобы его было просто понимать и т.д. Потому что мало где пишут код один раз и навсегда. Обычно код нужно развивать, дорабатывать и т.д. А код, написанный с глубокой оптимизацией, обычно понимать весьма непросто.
В общем, оптимизировать код можно по множеству разных характеристик и те две, которые вы назвали, обычно не самые важные, и уж как минимум, не единственные.
Кстати, могу привести ещё один пример. Есть такой сайт Kaggle, там проходят соревнования по машинному обучению. Так вот. К работе реальных дата сайентистов соревнования на Kaggle тоже имеют довольно далёкое отношение. То, что там делается - это только один-два этапа из реальной работы дата сайентистов. А этих этапов в реальной жизни гораздо больше и гонка за сотыми долями метрики как на каггле - это далеко не главное в реальной работе. Или даже вообще не существенно на самом деле по сравнению с другими характеристиками модели, над которой работает дата сайентист.
В общем, это можно сказать почти про любые соревнования. Это довольно далеко от реальной жизни, хотя и имеет некоторое отношение.

Спасибо большое! Я уж подумал, что и на работе нужно будет делать код, работающий для 267326747374372 тестов

@Das, зависит от работы. Тесты в том или ином виде будут в любом случае, просто они будут не синтетическими, как на олимпиадах.

@Das На работе нужно будет не только делать код, работающий для 267326747374372 тестов, но еще и писать сами эти тесты, и ище выяснять, что вообще требуется от этого кода, и все время переделывать его под изменившиеся требования.

@user7860670 Но 99.99% тестов при этом будут не на скорость, а на бизнес-логику )

@Das Грубо говоря, если у вас не сверхвысоконагруженное приложение, то можете даже сортировку пузырьком использовать, если скорость работы вашего приложения устроит потребителей. Хотя тим лид за такое не похвалит, но в целом будет "сомнительно, но ок". )

@CrazyElf, понял, спасибо!

мой плюс за офтоп, но ответ в точку

@Dmitry Я и сам за офтоп проголосовал, но не смог сдержаться от ответа ))
